# Symfony how to render child forms in a form collection one row at a time in a table in a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, formcollection

I have a form collection of child forms which is displayed at once (all child forms one after another).
but my requirement is to show one child form in a cell of an html table along with other related data of the same entity, like example below:

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>task 1</td>
      <td>child  form1 <input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>task 2</td>
      <td>child  form2 <input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>task 3</td>
      <td>child  form3 <input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: It is documented here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: The default block to edit ist here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L328